# Can you make advanced UI's with storyboards?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Is it possible to make an advanced UI, such as the twitter app for iPad, using storyboards? I am new to them and all the reading I have done on storyboards make them seem rather simplistic. Can you do most everything you could with nibs with a storyboard?

Comment: Your question is actually two questions: "Is it possible to make an advanced UI, such as the twitter app for iPad, using storyboards?" and "Can you do most everything you could with nibs with a storyboard?", in general, you should either generalize to one question, or post them in different posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A storyboard isn't much different from a group of .xibs. The advantage they provide is that you can see the relationship between the different view controllers. So sure -- anything you can do with a .xib you can also do with a storyboard.